# Specifying Schema of CSV in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting an error in what should be a simple case:

I want to read a bunch of CSVs, all have the same format, but no headers.

So, I am trying to specify the headers.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([        
    StructField("c0", StringType(), True),    
    StructField("c1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c3", TimestampType, True),
    StructField("c4", TimestampType, True),
    StructField("c5", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c6", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c7", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c8", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c9", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c10", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c11", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c12", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c13", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c14", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c15", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c16", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c17", StringType(), True)    
    ])

df = sqlContext.read.load('good_loc.csv', 
                          format='com.databricks.spark.csv', 
                          header='false', 
                          inferSchema='true')
```

I get the error:

```
dataType should be DataType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 403, in __init__
    assert isinstance(dataType, DataType), "dataType should be DataType"
AssertionError: dataType should be DataType
```

The error I think is coming from TimeStamp Type. I am using Spark 2.2

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If there is no header then why `header='true'`?

Comment: You forgot to initialize `TimestatmpType`: `StructField("c4", TimestampType(), True)`. And you never use the schema.

Comment: @user9613318 could yu show it as working code..why should I initialize like this..timestamp data format is supported in spark by default right?

Comment: Already did. Please compare your code (`StructField("c4", TimestampType, True)`) to the one shown in the comment above (missing `()`).

Comment: @ShankarKoirala both properties are false..still the same error

Comment: @user9613318 plz put it as the answer..silly mistake..thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. I think we can count it as a  simple typographical error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StructField("c3", TimestampType, True),
StructField("c4", TimestampType, True),
```

to become

```
StructField("c3", TimestampType(), True),
StructField("c4", TimestampType(), True),
```